# How to filter by many criterias using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsfiddle

So i was checking out a way to create a search function that filters using results based many criteria that is retrieved from the database by checking the checkbox. and i found the jsfiddle code here from http://jsfiddle.net/magicalex/FmQvc/.

It works with one variable bedroom and when i added bathroom criteria it works correctly but when i want to filter based on both variables.

```
$(window).load(function(){
$('input').change(function(){
var allchecked=0;
$('input').each(function(){
    var checked;
    if (checked = $(this).attr('checked')) {allchecked++};
    var numberofrooms = $('li[data-bedrooms='+$(this).data('bedrooms')+']');
    checked ?  numberofrooms.show('slow'): numberofrooms.hide('slow');

    var numberofbathrooms = $('li[data-  bathrooms='+$(this).data('bathrooms')+']');
    checked ?  numberofbathrooms.show('slow'): numberofbathrooms.hide('slow');
});
if(allchecked==0){$('li').show('slow');}
});
```

Example:
1 bedroom 2 bathroom are checked this shouldn't bring out any result.

```
<body>
<input data-bedrooms="1" type="checkbox">1 bedrooms<br>
<input data-bedrooms="2" type="checkbox">2 bedrooms<br>
<input data-bedrooms="3" type="checkbox">3 bedrooms<br><br>

<input data-bathrooms="1" type="checkbox">1 bathrooms<br>
<input data-bathrooms="2" type="checkbox">2 bathrooms<br>
<ul>
<li data-bedrooms="1" data-bathrooms="1">1 bedroom apartment</li>
<li data-bedrooms="1" data-bathrooms="1">1 bedroom apartment</li>
<li data-bedrooms="3" data-bathrooms="2">3 bedroom apartment</li>
<li data-bedrooms="2">2 bedroom apartment</li>
<li data-bedrooms="2">2 bedroom apartment</li>
<li data-bedrooms="2">2 bedroom apartment</li>
<li data-bedrooms="3" data-bathrooms="2">3 bedroom apartment</li>
<li data-bedrooms="2">2 bedroom apartment</li>
<li data-bedrooms="1" data-bathrooms="1">1 bedroom apartment</li>
<li data-bedrooms="2">2 bedroom apartment</li>
</ul>

</body>
```

But that is not what appears , it brings out the three bedrooms based on the two bathroom criteria that is checked.

Comment: Those `...data-...data...` selectors look very dodgy to me.

Comment: by adding additional piece of code you actually made it like "LOGICAL OR": you selects items matching the first critera, and you selects items matching the second criteria. they are independent of each other. You need to fix it so that they perform LOGICAL AND.

Comment: Why aren't you using radio buttons instead? Considering that you want a single-choice selection

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find all *li* elements which contain both a data-bedroom attribute and a data-bathroom attribute, you need to use a selector which matches both

```
$('li[data-bedrooms='+$(this).data('bedrooms')+'][data-bathrooms='+$(this).data('bathrooms')+']')
```